# Wordpress Featured Image meta box not showing

Tags: images, metabox

For some reason, the Featured Image box is not showing. I checked under the screen options and it is not showing. Since it is an MU site, I even checked under the main dashboard and still, I'm not seeing that option. I also checked for the setting under the settings and I don't still see the option.

Here is what I have:
WPBakery Page Builder as the main editor and my current version of Wordpress is 5.1.1 .

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: Try with add GLOBAL $post, before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be facing this problem because your theme does not support featured images.

But you can easily add that support, so no worries :)

To quote the [WordPress Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/):

> Themes must declare support for the Featured Image function before the
>   Featured Image interface will appear on the Edit screen. Support is
>   declared by putting the following in your theme’s `functions.php` file:

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

So just add that line to `functions.php` (of your own theme or child theme), and you will be able to see the Featured Image option after you save and refresh the admin area page.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to assist. If you later find that you are missing further functionality, you'll find [how to enable them at the handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/).